# Stellar Bifrost JS SDK Getting error says params.recoveryPublicKey is invalid

Tags: stellar-sdk, bifrost

As per the instructions I modified the example.html file from
https://github.com/stellar-deprecated/bifrost-js-sdk

I set the params as follows:

```
var params = {
    network: 'test',
    horizonURL: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
    bifrostURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
    recoveryPublicKey: 'GBJWOWMXNBW2UOWIXHVVTUBTIWBOAB2MV7YCQ4UF5TLZV7VS53CJHDFY'
  };
```

But I get the error:  params.recoveryPublicKey is invalid
Because the instructions say this parameter is optional, I deleted it as follows:

```
var params = {
    network: 'test',
    horizonURL: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
    bifrostURL: 'http://localhost:8002',
    horizonAllowHttp: true
  };
```

And as expected no longer got the error.

My questions is why am I getting the error? I am using the same format for the recoveryPublicKey as example.html and the key is valid.

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
 if (params.recoveryPublicKey !== undefined) {
            if (!_stellarSdk.StrKey.isValidEd25519PublicKey(params.recoveryPublicKey)) {
              throw new Error('params.recoveryPublicKey is invalid');
            }
```

Its part of this script in bifrost.js for the JS SDK

```
{
        key: '_checkParams',
        value: function _checkParams(params) {
          if (params === undefined) {
            throw new Error("params not provided");
          }

          if (['live', 'test'].indexOf(params.network) == -1) {
            throw new Error("Invalid params.network");
          }

          var requiredParams = ['bifrostURL', 'horizonURL'];
          var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
          var _didIteratorError = false;
          var _iteratorError = undefined;

          try {
            for (var _iterator = requiredParams[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
              var param = _step.value;

              if (typeof params[param] != 'string') {
                throw new Error('params.' + param + ' required and must be of type \'string\'');
              }
            }
          } catch (err) {
            _didIteratorError = true;
            _iteratorError = err;
          } finally {
            try {
              if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator['return']) {
                _iterator['return']();
              }
            } finally {
              if (_didIteratorError) {
                throw _iteratorError;
              }
            }
          }

          if (params.recoveryPublicKey !== undefined) {
            if (!_stellarSdk.StrKey.isValidEd25519PublicKey(params.recoveryPublicKey)) {
              throw new Error('params.recoveryPublicKey is invalid');
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the servers and browser and cleared the cache a couple of times and the error went away.  Now it works with recoveryPublicKey: 'GBJWOWMXNBW2UOWIXHVVTUBTIWBOAB2MV7YCQ4UF5TLZV7VS53CJHDFY'. =) =(